# sympy: group given expressions within other expressions, e.g. $a + 2 x y + b x + 2 x z$

Tags: symbolic-computation

I would like to use sympy to locate and group instances of a given symbolic expression within a set of expressions, so that the given expression may be replaced by a variable.  For instance, with expressions like

`a + 2 * x * y + b * x + 2 * x * z`

I would like to group factors of an expression such as `y + z`, to obtain

`a + b * x + 2 * x * (y + z)`

and then substitute symbol `w` for `y + z`:

`a + b * x + 2 * x * w`

What is the proper way to achieve that?

Comment: isn't this a programming problem?

Comment: I hope SymPy can do the grouping for me, without substantial programming effort. I have tried replace(), but it doesn't seem very good at finding multi-term expressions.  It works if the exact expression is already grouped within the input expression.